# php create file in a new directory

Tags: php, fwrite, directory-structure

I need create a new txt file in a new directory. I do thi code

```
$path="dir1";
mkdir("$path",0777);

$path1="dir1/dir2";
mkdir("$path1",0777);

$path2="dir1/dir2/dir3";
mkdir("$path2",0777);


$percorso=$path.$path1.$path2;

$var=fopen($percorso."/nome_file.txt","a+");
fwrite($var, "stringa di prova");
```

It creates the 3 directory dir1/dir2/dir3 on my server but not the file. why?

Comment: What error do you get? `$percorso` looks something like 'dir1dir1/dir2dir1/dir2/dir3'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$path="dir1";
mkdir("$path",0777);

$path1="dir1/dir2";
mkdir("$path1",0777);

$path2="dir1/dir2/dir3";
mkdir("$path2",0777);


$percorso=$path2;

$var=fopen($percorso."/nome_file.txt","a+");
fwrite($var, "stringa di prova");
```

Answer (score 0):

$path2 witll be sufficient

```
$var=fopen($path2."/nome_file.txt","a+");
```

Comment: Instead of '/' you should use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : http://www.php.net/manual/ro/dir.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

Because if `$path="dir1"` and `$path1="dir1/dir2"` and `$path2="dir1/dir2/dir3"`, the code `$percorso=$path.$path1.$path2` will give you :

```
dir1dir1/dir2dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Just change
`$var=fopen($percorso."/nome_file.txt","a+");`
to
`$var=fopen($path2."/nome_file.txt","a+");`